# How to get innerHTML for a particular html element through its class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml

I have HTML code like this:

```
<div class="a">html value 1</div>

<div class="a">html value 2</div>
```

How can I access `html value 1` and `html value 2` using jquery?

Comment: Code like what? Give a proper code example or it will be hard to understand what you actually mean.

Comment: i am new to stack overflow. that's why such mistake happened

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.a')[0].innerHTML;
$('.a')[1].innerHTML;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zE2eM/)

Comment: Iam wondering when he wanted to use this method then why don't he use Javascript only

Answer (score 7):

Separately:

```
$('div.a:eq(0)').html(); // $('div.a:eq(0)').text();
$('div.a:eq(1)').html(); // $('div.a:eq(1)').text();
```

Using loop:

```
$('div.a').each(function() {
   console.log( $(this).html() ); //or $(this).text();
});
```

Using `.html()`

```
​$('div.a').html(function(i, oldHtml) {
  console.log( oldHtml )
})​​;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2HpN7/)**

Using `.text()`

```
$('div.a').text(function(i, oldtext) {
  console.log( oldtext )
})​;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2HpN7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    alert(a[i].innerHTML)
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5QsAt/1/)