# WordPress, Email certain part of the page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm currently developing a page which needs certain parts of the content to be emailed to myself.

In the code, is a loop, which gets all the information, so it would need to literally be a copy of the text on their screen.

I did try the following:

```
<a href="mailto:email@emailaddres.com?subject=Test&body=<?php urlencode(the_permalink()) ?>">Email this link to a friend </a>
```

which emailed myself only the link to the page, which would not work as the information will be saved using cookies.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this, maybe by only emailing the content in a certain class?

EDIT

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
   function getContent() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('email-class');
  var b = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b+=a[i].innerHTML;
  }
  return b;
}
});

</script>
        <div id="primary" class="content-area container">
            <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12">


                        <div class="email-class">
                        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                        <p><?php echo do_shortcode('[user_favorites user_id="" include_links="true" site_id="" post_types="" include_buttons="false"]');?></p>
                        </div>
<a href="mailto:email@emailaddres.com?subject=Test&body=" onclick="this.href += getContent();">Email this content to a friend </a>


                </div>

            </main><!-- .site-main -->
        </div><!-- .content-area -->
```

Comment: I would recommend you, to use jquery to get some part of the page and send an ajax request to your script with the nessesary data, and mail it!

Comment: Why you not create PHP mail function and send daily email or each day?

Comment: @GourabNag how would this be implemented, any links/tutorials would be great

Comment: @jdloader I am writing out an answer for you..

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any ideas how to do this, maybe by only emailing the content in a certain class?

```
function getContent() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName('your-class');
  var b = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b+=a[i].innerHTML;
  }
  return b;
}
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11666892/1124793

The function will return a string of all the content in the class 'your-class' . You can then email it to yourself using the method you tried:

```
<a href="mailto:email@emailaddres.com?subject=Test&body=" onclick="this.href += getContent();">Email this content to a friend </a>
```

This will append the content you get from `getContent()` from above onto the mailto link you originally tried and therefore put it into the body field of whatever email client you're using.

Comment: The above doesn't seem to work, i think the function is the issue, it seems to make the page just turn white, maybe a PHP error?

Comment: There's no PHP in the code in this answer and I checked the code for syntactic validity. Did you change 'your-class' to an existing class name in your wordpress site?

Comment: I placed it and it has worked, apologies, but It isnt displaying any information?

Comment: don't put the function getContent() inside $(document).ready. Put it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this could work out for you:

#### index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a onclick="send()" id="email_content">Content to be derlivered</a>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                function send(){
                    var inside_html = $("#email_content").html();
                    $.post("send.php", {data: inside_html}, function(data){console.log("success");});
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### send.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    //reference here for more details in mail() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
    $html = $_POST["data"];
    $to = "CHANGE THIS";
    $subject = "CHANGE THIS TOO";
    $body = $html;
    $headers = "FROM: `PLACE-YOUR-EMAIL-ADDRESS-HERE`\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}
?>
```

Suggested reading - 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I tired the above, the link won't open anything at all?

Comment: Check your browser console after clicking the link and see if there is a message succesd